# Why are people selling Training Manuals in the Trading Post?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I just noticed that there are Training manuals being sold in the Trading Post.

Why is anyone selling these when you buy them from trainers?

Is there something I'm missing here? Is there another way to acquire them other than trainers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can buy a training manual from a vendor even when after you've used one.  People buy them by mistake and try to sell them at the Trading Post in order to make some of the money back.

People will put in orders for them in order to save a bit of money.

Comment: It is also worth noting that a training manual can be used to reset your traits without talking to your class trainer. Apparently people occasionally use them for re-spec-ing in dungeons, etc.

Comment: @sjohnston When I first started playing, I thought buying training manuals _was_ the way to respec.  I couldn't find any way to use the training manual since I had already used it once before.